# NoSuchMethod during in-route EDIFACT unmarshal

Tags: java, scala, apache-camel, spring-camel, smooks

I'm trying to make unmarshalling a file in a camel route work. I'm using the SmooksDataFormat to do so. Currently I have these things configured:

**Route:**

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        SmooksDataFormat sdf = new SmooksDataFormat("smooks-config.xml");

        from("file:src/test/resources/input?delete=true&moveFailed=.failed")
                .routeId("route")
                .unmarshal(sdf)
                .to("mock:done");

        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

**smooks-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="https://www.smooks.org/xsd/smooks-2.0.xsd"
                      xmlns:edifact="https://www.smooks.org/xsd/smooks/edifact-2.0.xsd">

    <edifact:parser schemaURI="/d96a/EDIFACT-Messages.dfdl.xsd">
        <edifact:messageTypes>
            <edifact:messageType>ORDERS</edifact:messageType>
        </edifact:messageTypes>
    </edifact:parser>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

**Dependencies: *(I've tried using the 2.0.0-M3 versions too, but that results in the same exception)***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.smooks.cartridges</groupId>
    <artifactId>smooks-camel-cartridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.smooks.cartridges.edi</groupId>
    <artifactId>smooks-edifact-cartridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.smooks.cartridges.edi</groupId>
    <artifactId>edifact-schemas</artifactId>
    <classifier>d96a</classifier>
    <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>

# Camel version
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Trying to run this result in this exception though:

```
org.smooks.api.SmooksConfigException: Error invoking @PostConstruct method 'postConstruct' on class 'org.smooks.cartridges.dfdl.parser.DfdlParser'.
    at org.smooks.engine.lifecycle.AbstractLifecyclePhase.invoke(AbstractLifecyclePhase.java:79)
    at org.smooks.engine.lifecycle.PostConstructLifecyclePhase.doApply(PostConstructLifecyclePhase.java:88)
    at org.smooks.engine.lifecycle.AbstractLifecyclePhase.apply(AbstractLifecyclePhase.java:61)
    at org.smooks.engine.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleManager.applyPhase(DefaultLifecycleManager.java:53)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.JavaContentHandlerFactory.create(JavaContentHandlerFactory.java:94)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ContentHandlerExtractionStrategy.addContentDeliveryUnit(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:442)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ContentHandlerExtractionStrategy.applyContentDeliveryUnitStrategy(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:386)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ContentHandlerExtractionStrategy.applyStrategy(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:373)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ResourceConfigTableIterator.iterate(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:524)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder$ResourceConfigTableIterator.access$200(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:504)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.extractContentHandlers(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:346)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.load(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:238)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.build(DefaultContentDeliveryConfigBuilder.java:140)
    at org.smooks.engine.delivery.DefaultContentDeliveryRuntimeFactory.create(DefaultContentDeliveryRuntimeFactory.java:86)
    at org.smooks.engine.DefaultExecutionContext.<init>(DefaultExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.smooks.engine.DefaultExecutionContext.<init>(DefaultExecutionContext.java:94)
    at org.smooks.Smooks.createExecutionContext(Smooks.java:447)
    at org.smooks.Smooks.createExecutionContext(Smooks.java:405)
    at org.smooks.cartridges.camel.dataformat.SmooksDataFormat.unmarshal(SmooksDataFormat.java:127)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:469)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:184)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:492)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:245)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:206)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:202)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.smooks.api.SmooksConfigException: org.smooks.api.SmooksConfigException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object scala.Some.value()'
    at org.smooks.cartridges.edi.EdiDataProcessorFactory.createDataProcessor(EdiDataProcessorFactory.java:87)
    at org.smooks.cartridges.dfdl.parser.DfdlParser.postConstruct(DfdlParser.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.smooks.engine.lifecycle.AbstractLifecyclePhase.invoke(AbstractLifecyclePhase.java:75)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.smooks.api.SmooksConfigException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object scala.Some.value()'
    at org.smooks.cartridges.edifact.EdifactDataProcessorFactory.doCreateDataProcessor(EdifactDataProcessorFactory.java:115)
    at org.smooks.cartridges.edi.EdiDataProcessorFactory.createDataProcessor(EdiDataProcessorFactory.java:85)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object scala.Some.value()'
    at org.apache.daffodil.util.Misc$.getRequiredResource(Misc.scala:202)
    at org.apache.daffodil.util.Misc.getRequiredResource(Misc.scala)
    at org.smooks.cartridges.edifact.EdifactDataProcessorFactory.readVersion(EdifactDataProcessorFactory.java:136)
    at org.smooks.cartridges.edifact.EdifactDataProcessorFactory.doCreateDataProcessor(EdifactDataProcessorFactory.java:95)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

**My dependency tree:**

```
[INFO] nl.smooks.test:smooks-test:jar:1.0                                   
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.5:compile 
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.5:compile                
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile                   
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile                   
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile         
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile                          
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile         
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.27:compile                                 
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.4.5:compile    
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.4:compile      
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.45:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.45:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-management-api:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-main:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-main:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-base:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-xml-jaxb-dsl:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core-model:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-processor:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-dsl-support:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-endpointdsl:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-cloud:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-cluster:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-base-engine:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-health:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-core-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-engine:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-api:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-core-reifier:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-util:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-bean-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-bean:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-browse-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-browse:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-controlbus-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-controlbus:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-dataformat-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-dataformat:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-dataset-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-dataset:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-direct-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-direct:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-directvm-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-directvm:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-file-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-file:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-language-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-language:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-log-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-log:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-mock-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-mock:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-ref-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-ref:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-rest-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-rest:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-tooling-model:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.camel:camel-util-json:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-saga-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-saga:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-scheduler-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-scheduler:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-seda-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-seda:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-stub-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-stub:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-timer-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-timer:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-validator-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-validator:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-vm-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-vm:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-xpath-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-xpath:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-xslt-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-xslt:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-xml-jaxp-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-xml-jaxp:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.camel:camel-xml-io-util:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-jmx-starter:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-jmx:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.camel:camel-support:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-management:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.smooks.cartridges:smooks-camel-cartridge:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.smooks.cartridges:smooks-javabean-cartridge:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.smooks:smooks-core:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.smooks:smooks-commons:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.smooks:smooks-api:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.31:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.18:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.4.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.8:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:smooks-edifact-cartridge:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:smooks-edi-cartridge:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:edi-schemas:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.smooks.cartridges:smooks-dfdl-cartridge:jar:1.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-japi_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.11:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-core_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-runtime1-unparser_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  +- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-runtime1_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-io_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  |     \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-lib_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-runtime1-layers_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-udf_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.lihaoyi:os-lib_2.12:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- com.lihaoyi:geny_2.12:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:70.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-scala_2.12:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.10:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:edifact-schemas:jar:d96a:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.4.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.4.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.5:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.18.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.6.28:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.13:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] \- org.apache.camel:camel-test-spring-junit5:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-test-junit5:jar:3.14.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-languages:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-xml:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.camel:camel-xml-jaxb:jar:3.14.0:compile
[INFO]       |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]       |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO]       \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-xml:jar:3.14.0:compile
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: My bet is that you have a dependency conflict on Scala. Can you edit your question to show the list of dependencies you get when running `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @Claude I've added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out that this wrong version of the `scala-library` came from my dependency management dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

After updating it to this, it does bring in the right version:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the wrong version of `scala-library` is being pulled down by Maven. In your dependency tree, the version of `scala-library` is 2.11.11 while on my machine it's 2.12.15:

```
[INFO] org.smooks.cartridges.edi:smooks-edifact-cartridge:jar:2.0.0-RC1
[INFO] +- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:smooks-edi-cartridge:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:edi-schemas:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] +- org.smooks.cartridges.edi:edifact-schemas:jar:d03b:2.0.0-RC1:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.smooks.cartridges:smooks-dfdl-cartridge:jar:1.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.smooks:smooks-core:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.smooks:smooks-commons:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.smooks:smooks-api:jar:2.0.0-RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.4.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-japi_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.15:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-core_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-runtime1-unparser_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-runtime1_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-io_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |     \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-lib_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-runtime1-layers_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.daffodil:daffodil-udf_2.12:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.lihaoyi:os-lib_2.12:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.lihaoyi:geny_2.12:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:70.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-scala_2.12:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.17.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:test
[INFO] \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.2:test
```